# How to type in Chinese pinyin tones on Dvorak keyboard on macOS?

Tags: mac, keyboard, dvorak

I want to type in Chinese pinyin and found [a website](http://pinpinchinese.com/blog/how-to-type-pinyin-tone-marks-mac-os-x-yosemite/), but it only works for second (é) and fourth (è) tones. The first and third tones don't work on Dvorak, as Option + a and Option + k input å and ˚, respectively.

In Dvorak, how can I type in these remaining Chinese tones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only type 3 tones on Dvorak (or on US for that matter).  To include the 3rd tone you have to use ABC Extended, which is qwerty.  You can make a custom Dvorak layout which adds the missing tone with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).